# Older version of Android Studio not found (Electric Eel)

Tags: android-studio

I have recently update Android Studio to Flamingo version but I want to revert to Electric Eel (they have changed Empty Activity with Java language, to Basic Views Activity and it adds unwanted features to the project). In the archive page of older versions I cannot find any Electric Eel release. Does anybody know an alternative place to find all older versions?
Thank you

Comment: just search `android studio archives` in google it is like a repository for all old versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find them [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive). Scroll down, agree to the terms and you will get a full list with all available versions, including Electric Eel.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeQrX.png)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for both answers, but the problem was another:
I was in that page already, but didn't appear all the old versions. I have found why. The problem was the language: it detects than the search is made from Spain and automatically sends you  : [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive?hl=es-419). If you make the search from France sends you to:[this one](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive?hl=fr), and from England (eg.) to [that one](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive?hl=en). And doesn't appear the same versions in each one (for instance from Spain only appears until 2021). I don't know if it is because they are translated versions, but they don't know if you want a translated one or the original version.It's a problem if you don't know it.

Comment: wow thank you so much, unbeliveable that when using spanish, it only gets to 2021 versions